# Is there any color picker RTE in typo3 neos?

Tags: neoscms

I was wondering if there any color picker RTE that we can implement in the back-end of TYPO3 NEOS.

Answer (score 0):

So far there is none. We will organize a codesprint dedicated to improving editor extensibility and configuration to address those issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can patch Aloha RTE https://jira.neos.io/browse/NEOS-468 and add custom plugin http://www.alohaeditor.org/guides/plugin_textcolor.html